# Navigation bar exceeds the width of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar, nav

I'm currently working on a site that a an ex-colleague started on and I've noticed that every time the browser window's resolution gets to 768px or lower the navigation turns in to a drop down menu, which seems to be wider than the page itself. 
And there's a horizontal scroll bar on the bottom allowing the user to scroll to the right where there's a bunch of white space next to the page.

(here's a picture of the problem I'm having)

[image]

Because I didn't built this page from scratch I'm not entirely sure what code I can delete and I'm not entirely sure where the problem lies.
Nor am I that sure of which part of the code to post here.

I did search the site for questions similar to mine and some posts spoke about changing the "overflow" settings but that unfortunately didn't solve the problem for me. 
I do apologise if there's an exact same post as mine.

I've uploaded the site at:
http://ariellafreinders.co.uk/LGA/copy.html
(so if anyone would like to have a look at the code they can do so there.)

Initially I thought it would it make sense to assume that the error lies somewhere in the media queries because this problem only exists in smaller resolutions, but I'm having second thoughts.

I hope my post made sense, thanks for your time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using. It might help to create a reproducible example on JsFiddle or similiar to make it easier to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `#attraction_items` element is wider than its parent, causing the page to scroll horizontally.

Try this:

```
#attraction_items {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* margin-left: -12.5px; */
  /* margin-right: -12.5px; */
}
```

If you comment out those two negative margins, the page doesn't scroll horizontally.

Looks like your former co-worker was trying to compensate for the margins on the child elements with class `col_tiles_1`

```
.col_tiles_1, .col_tiles_2, .col_tiles_3, .col_tiles_4, .col_tiles_5, .col_tiles_6, .col_tiles_7, .col_tiles_8, .col_tiles_9, .col_tiles_10, .col_tiles_11, .col_tiles_12, .col_tiles_13, .col_tiles_14 {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 344px;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 12.5px;
  margin-right: 12.5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I initially thought it was a navigation problem, but after I completely removed the navigation from the page I found that that wasn't the case. Your explanation makes sense, and it also explains why that code would be there.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when a customer of mine has this problem, it's because their content (mainly text) goes beyond the viewport. An example would be, a long word in a heading, making the last couple letters exceed the container (as word-breaking is not standard).

Please scroll down the page and look for any occurrences of this.

A quick fix that I usually use is in CSS:

```
* {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This fixes most of such errors. You can pick specific elements instead of a wildcard.

I tried applying that css to your page and it fixed it. A fix however is not usually appreciated by the community, so I'll give you an explanation:

The reason for this is that you have elements that exceed, as mentioned. Why?

Your padding on the title blocks adds extra width, you should apply a

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

to it's styling. You have some elements:

```
.col_tiles_1, 
.col_tiles_2,
.col_tiles_3,
.col_tiles_4, 
.col_tiles_5,
.col_tiles_6,
.col_tiles_7,
.col_tiles_8,
.col_tiles_9,
.col_tiles_10,
.col_tiles_11,
.col_tiles_12,
.col_tiles_13,
.col_tiles_14 {
    ...
    margin-left: 12.5px;
    margin-right: 12.5px;
    ...
}
```

That makes the boxes append a margin to the right, hence making the whitespace.

The fastest fix would be the max-width attribute, but it may not be preferable to everyone.

I hope this helps, otherwise let me know and I'll go in-debt.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment out the negative margins from the attraction items. In main.css, change:

```
#attraction_items{
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -12.5px;
    margin-right: -12.5px;
}
```

to

```
#attraction_items{
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin-left: -12.5px;
    margin-right: -12.5px;*/
}
```